# Как узнать, находиться ли точка внутри эллипса?

Tags: c++, геометрия, sfml

Так вот, пишу курсовую и встал. Взял класс `ellipseShape` c страницы  `sfml`. Все рисует все работает

Но вот попадание внутрь не могу реализовать. Совет использовать каноническую уравнение эллипса не подходит потому, что не могу найти `a` и `b`. Если можно же все таки, найти посоветуйте. Может, как-то с помощью библиотечных методов?

Хедер файл:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics/Shape.hpp>
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace sf;
class EllipseShape : public sf::Shape
{
private:
Vector2f m_radius;
public:
EllipseShape* ellipse;
 explicit EllipseShape(const Vector2f& radius = Vector2f(0.f, 0.f)) : m_radius(radius){
update();
 }
 void setRadius(const Vector2f& radius);
 const Vector2f& getRadius() const;
 virtual size_t getPointCount() const;
 virtual Vector2f getPoint(size_t index) const;

};
```

cpp файл:

```cpp
#include "EllipseShape.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void EllipseShape::setRadius(const Vector2f& radius)
{
    m_radius = radius;
    update();
}
const Vector2f& EllipseShape::getRadius() const
{
    return m_radius;
}
size_t EllipseShape::getPointCount() const
{
    return 30; // fixed, but could be an attribute of the class if needed
}
Vector2f EllipseShape::getPoint(std::size_t index) const
{
    static const float pi = 3.141592654f;

    float angle = index * 2 * pi / getPointCount() - pi / 2;
    float x = cos(angle) * m_radius.x;
    float y = sin(angle) * m_radius.y;

    return Vector2f(m_radius.x + x, m_radius.y + y);
}
```

Comment: А там это разве настоящий эллипс, а не просто растянутый круг?

Comment: А это, по-вашему, что?  `m_radius.x m_radius.y`

Comment: @Kromster Эллипс в общем-то и  есть растянутый круг

Comment: это, конечно, растянутый круг, но дело не в этом, я вот как понял в итоге, что m_radius это  a и b а не фокальные радиусы потому, что их задаю; это решение если предположить что это все же фокальные радиусы:  нашел, вот, такое решение и оно не работает : 
Vector2f EllipseShape::axes()
{

    std::size_t index = 15;
   Vector2f M = getPoint(index);// (x,y) x = 0, y = b;
   float a = (getRadius().x + getRadius().y) / 2;
   float b = M.y;
   Vector2f AB = { a, b };

    return AB;
}я пробовал уже с тем, что a и b это m_radius но тоже ошибка  одним словом я в тупике

Comment: bool SelectableEllipse::isPointInside(Vector2f point) { Vector2f AB = axes(); return (point.x * point.x) / (ellipse->axes().x * ellipse->axes().x) + (point.y * point.y) / (ellipse->axes().y * ellipse->axes().y) <= 1; } это в производном классе ellipse указатель на EllipseShape –

Comment: фокальные радиусы - НЕ являются характеристиками эллипса. Вам это понятие здесь совсем не нужно. m_radius.x и y - это полуоси a и b

Comment: @MBo, получается, что можно пользоваться m_radius и каноническим уравнением эллипса x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2 = 1 где а и b m_radius.x и y и надо будет возможно делать сдвиг относительно центра координат (x-x0) (y-y0) с помощью какой функции можно узнать положения центра эллипса: getPosition() или getOrigin ? не могли бы подсказать как это бы выглядело примерно?

Comment: всем спасибо, я разобрался, использовал каноническое уравнение эллипса, и нормально разобрался в том как работает setOrigin  в связке с setPosition. Оказалось, что сначала надо выставить позицию объекта то есть эллипса (ellipse->setPosition(w,h), а потом уже внутри объекта( это называется локальная система координат ) выставить центральную точку от которой все и считаем то есть x0, y0) c помощью setOrigin() ellipse -> setOrigin(m_radius.x, m_radius.y) в конструкторе, где создавали эллипс. Надеюсь, что мои мучения, кому-нибудь будут нужны

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nb2RI48JH4g&t=3758s на 1ч 2 минуты смотрите

Answer (score 0):

1. Переносим начало координат в центр эллипса (так проще). Т.е. от положения точки отнимаем положение эллипса, а положение эллипса делаем 0:0.
2. Узнаем ширину *w* и высоту *d* эллипса (он же у вас ориентирован по осям?).
3. Рассчитываем коэффициент *f* растяжения по высоте (*w* / *d*).
4. Умножаем положение проверяемой точки по высоте на этот коэффициент *f*.
5. Теперь у нас типовая задачка на попадание точки в круг радиуса *w/2*. Решаете.